# Index duplicates in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Index only duplicates in a multidimensional array.

Example

```
a = [[279, 629, 590], [382, 825, 279], [629, 569, 113], [382, 785, 296]]
```

3D array with duplicates, I want to return the row and column of duplicates.

```
results = [[[279], [[0, 0], [1, 3]], [[629], [[0, 1], [2, 0]], [[382], [[1, 0], [3, 0]]]
```

I am looking to return only the duplicate elements along with the row and columns.

Comment: That's an interesting problem; how have you tried to solve it?

Comment: Is using Numpy an option?  It would make things easier.  (And technically, there are no arrays in the Python core language, let alone multi-dimensional arrays.  There are lists of lists, but that's something different, and the difference matters in some cases.)

Comment: I really didn't know where to start with solving this problem. I  like to provide attempts to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: I think I can use numpy to get the column and row length and then loop through the multidimensional array, adding found duplicates to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for this problem is to get a `dict` (I used a `defaultdict` because it is nicer if one doesn't need to initiate empty lists by hand) where the key is the value and the value is a list of the coordinates for this value:

```
a = [[279, 629, 590], [382, 825, 279], [629, 569, 113], [382, 785, 296]]
from collections import defaultdict
elements = defaultdict(list)
for row_index in range(len(a)):
    for col_index in range(len(a[row_index])):
        elements[a[row_index][col_index]].append([row_index, col_index])
```

The next step would be to create a `list` of the value and the coordinates like you specified:

```
multiples = [[[i], elements[i]] for i in elements if len(elements[i]) > 1]
```

Which would be:

```
[[[629], [(0, 1), (2, 0)]],
 [[279], [(0, 0), (1, 2)]],
 [[382], [(1, 0), (3, 0)]]]
```